# How to take an array by props and render?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm building some info cards through React, and I'm passing the info through props to a base component.

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
    <Box className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.helpCards}>
                <CardBase title={WhatICanDo.title} list={WhatICanDo.links}/>
                <CardBase title={LearnToTalkToMe.title} />
                <CardBase title={QuickLinks.title} list={QuickLinks.links}/>
            </div>
    </Box>
```

I have a separate file where I store this information. The card is mainly given a title and a list of useful links.

```
export const WhatICanDo = {
    title: 'O que eu posso fazer?',
    links: [
        'Reset de Senha',
        'Dúvidas Frequentes'
    ]
}

export const LearnToTalkToMe = {
    title: 'Aprenda a falar comigo'
}

export const QuickLinks = {
    title: 'Links Rápidos',
    links: [
        'Reset de Senha',
        'Consulta de Ponto',
        'Criação de Chamados',
        'Consulta de Chamados',
        'Dúvidas Frequentes'
    ]
}
```

Inside the file that captures the information and assembles all the base of these cards, I need to make a map of the list of received links, so that they are all in the form of items (< li >).

```
export default function CardBase({ list, title }) {
    const cardsList = [list];

    function cardsMap() {
        return (
            <>
                {cardsList.map((card, index) => 
                    <li key={index}>{card}</li>
                )}
            </> 
        )
    }

    return (
        <Card className=''>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography className='' color='' gutterBottom>
                    {title}
                </Typography>
                
                <Typography className='' variant='' component=''>
                    {cardsMap()}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

Well, this all works very well. But when rendering, all the items in the list are next to each other and not one below the other as I wanted.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn6be.png)

how could I solve this?

Comment: This is working fine for me. check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/list-card-items-ghzkk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hi @NidhiDadiya, I highly recommend using the standard JSX Syntax to define components. Instead of `cardsMap` write `CardsMap` so that you can call the component like this `<CardsMap />` instead of `{cardsMap()}`. I made this mistake too when I started with react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line

```js
const cardsList = [list]
```

you are creating a new array filled with the goal array so your data structure looks like this

```js
[ // first array
 [ // second array
   'Reset de Senha',
   'Consulta de Ponto',
   'Criação de Chamados',
   'Consulta de Chamados',
   'Dúvidas Frequentes'
  ]
]
```

with your `cardsList.map` function you are just iterating over the first array which includes only one element (the second array). So just use `list.map` without the additional redeclaration of cardsList to iterate over the links.

**EDIT:**

You get the Error that `list` can't access `.map` because you didn't pass it as a prop in your second `CardBase` component. When you make it an optional like `list?.map((card, index) => ...))` it should work without the error (make it optional with an `?` after your `list`).

Answer (score 0):

`list` is an array, just use :

```
const cardsList = list; // not [list]
```

Comment: I try this. But don't work, get an error why list can't access map

Answer (score 0):

** Use this code

```
export default function CardBase({ list, title }) {

const cardsList = list; //not [list] as list is already an array

function cardsMap() {
    return (
        <>
            {cardsList.length && cardsList.map((card, index) => 
                <li key={index}>{card}</li>
            )}
        </> 
    )
}

return (
    <Card className=''>
        <CardContent>
            <Typography className='' color='' gutterBottom>
                {title}
            </Typography>
            
            <Typography className='' variant='' component=''>
                {cardsMap()}
            </Typography>
        </CardContent>
    </Card>
);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).